# C# projects using both X86 and Any CPU

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Say I have 2 Winform projects A, B.

Project A (target .NET 2.0) has to be run on x86 (it is an external library) and for legacy reasons project B (target .NET 4.0) has to be run on Any CPU. Now I need to call A's methods from project B but it throws an error:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'CSharpDemo, Version=1.0.5414.18636, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
```

However, I found if I target project B on .NET 4.5 then this problem doesn't occur. But I still want Project B to be targeting 4.0, how to achieve this?

Comment: AnyCPU prefer 32bit ?

Comment: mostly it should run on 32bits machine, but I can't change Project B's setting to x86 as it may affect other projects

Comment: It seems a dead end then. AnyCPU on 64bit OS means 64bit code and 64bit code cannot call 32bit libraries. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/

Comment: I see, so the reason why .NET 4.5 can run successful is because of its "Any CPU 32-bit preferred" setting, I wonder how can we make .NET 4.0 to achieve the same?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are saying:

1. Project A needs to call Project B's methods
2. Project A needs to run on x86
3. Project B needs to run on Any CPU

Comment: That's because in .net 4.5 you can compile the project as AnyCPU and mark it prefer 32-bit. Cannot do that if you compile it using .net 4.0

Comment: @Mayank: But doing that would be wrong, if it has a x86 dependency.

Comment: @Steve: I thin Sasha missed a couple important scenarios in that blog post :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If any of your code calls 32-bit x86 libraries, the entire process needs to load as x86.  No exceptions.

To do this, set the EXE project to x86, set DLL projects that have native x86 dependencies to x86, and for pure managed DLL projects you can use AnyCPU -- .NET will load them as x86 for your x86 EXE, but they can also load into x64 EXEs.

Remember that x86 code runs just fine on x64 processors running x64 Windows, with the help of the WOW64 compatibility layer.

(with limited exceptions: on Windows Server edition, WOW64 is an optional component, and in the preinstall environment there is no WOW64).

Comment: By EXE project, do you mean the start up project in Visual Studio ? I have everything using AnyCPU except the x86 library, hence it means I only need to change the startUp to x86 and leave the rest as they are right?

Comment: @wuha: The startup project would be an EXE project, yes.  Sometimes a solution has multiple EXEs, but your main program is an EXE for sure.

Answer (score 7):

You may find the answer to your question in following blog post

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/

Here is summary

.net 4.0

> What AnyCPU used to mean up to .NET 4.0 (and Visual Studio 2010) is the following:
>
> •If the process runs on a 32-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.
>
> •If the process runs on a 64-bit Windows system, it runs as a 64-bit process. IL is compiled to x64 machine code.
>
> •If the process runs on an Itanium Windows system (has anyone got one? ;-) ), it runs as a 64-bit process. IL is compiled to Itanium machine code.

.net 4.5

> In .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11 the cheese has been moved. The
>   default for most .NET projects is again AnyCPU, but there is more than
>   one meaning to AnyCPU now. There is an additional sub-type of AnyCPU,
>   “Any CPU 32-bit preferred”, which is the new default (overall, there
>   are now five options for the /platform C# compiler switch: x86,
>   Itanium, x64, anycpu, and anycpu32bitpreferred). When using that
>   flavor of AnyCPU, the semantics are the following:
>
> •If the process
>   runs on a 32-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is
>   compiled to x86 machine code.
>
> •If the process runs on a 64-bit Windows
>   system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to x86 machine
>   code.
>
> •If the process runs on an ARM Windows system, it runs as a
>   32-bit process. IL is compiled to ARM machine code.

Comment: Then it means there is no way to call methods of x86 project from an "Any CPU" project under .NET 4.0?

Comment: Although you can compile the same code in both .net 4.0 and 4.5 and use appropriate assemblies in projects.

Comment: @wuha: There is no way on ANY version of .NET, to use an x86 DLL from a non-x86 EXE.  In .NET 4.5, your project was loading as x86 due to the new default.

Comment: @BenVoigt even though the program finally runs on a 32bits machine ? At that time shouldn't AnyCPU fits into x86 accordingly?

Comment: @wuha: `AnyCPU` isn't a separate architecture.  It marks the file to conform to an architecture selected by the environment.  Sometimes that will be x86, which you NEED, and things will work.  But anytime the flexibility of AnyCPU kicks in, and some architecture other than x86 gets selected, your x86 dependency would fail to load.