# C# How can I use libraries which use a different CPU architecture?

Tags: c#, cpu, libraries

I am currently developing a standalone application using C#, and I am facing a problem for which I can't find a solution. Indeed, my script uses two libraries (provided by an external company), however, one is made for 64-bit systems and the other for 32-bit systems. So here is my problem, as soon as I try to use both libraries at the same time, I always get an error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException
```

I've already tried to build my project for "Any CPU", "x64" and "x86" but I always have the same problem.

So I would like to know if it is possible to solve this problem in order to be able to use both libraries in the same script or is there another technique to achieve the same result?

Thank you in advance,
Clément

Comment: You will have to spin up different processes for those two and load the respective assemblies into each, and then figure out communication between the two. **There is no way to load 32-bit and 64-bit assemblies into the same process.**

Comment: A different approach would be to reach out to the vendor and see if there is a way to get them to provide 32-bit or 64-bit versions of all those assemblies, so that you don't have to jump through hoops to load them.

Comment: Unfortunately the company supplying these libraries has recently closed... If I started processing the first library in an A script (64-bit) that would then use a B script (86-bit), the result could be conclusive?

Comment: Possibly, try to realize DLL-as-a-service approach with client-server over TCP. Server runs 32bit wrapper for your library, you ask him about actions. manually, gRPC, SignalR, WCF, etc.

Comment: Possibly, duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598558/c-sharp-projects-using-both-x86-and-any-cpu

Answer (score 0):

If the *libraries* use third-party standard *windows dlls* this will be a lot harder.

However, just *decompile* the library, and *rebuild* it in your chosen *bitness*.

---

<sub>***Note 1*** : Beware this might be infringing licence agreements</sub>

<sub>***Note 2*** : Some decompilers might be a little hit and miss</sub>

Comment: If you don't have access to the source and have to de-compile, you are most likely violating the license agreement.

Comment: @TsahiAsher Given that the OP said the vendor company recently closed, does it matter?

Comment: @NetMage IANAL, but a closed company doesn't mean all it's copyright is void. It may have sold its patents in order to return debts, for example.

Comment: @TsahiAsher True, but you said license agreement. I suppose it depends on if it went out of business or was purchased or sold, and what the agreement says in those cases. But if it is out of business, who would enforce the terms?

Comment: @NetMage Fair point. Still, it's likely a copyright violation.