# "hostfxr.dll failed" error when my application published with self-contained and x64 call x86 application

Tags: .net, winforms

I published my winform application(on .net6.0-windows) with self-contained and win-x64 options.
And this project refers a console app(net6.0-windows and platformtarget is x86).

- project a : Main Application - winforms, .net6.0-windows, any cpu
- proejct b : Tool Application - console app, .net6.0-windows, x86

"A" winform application which published above publish options runs fine.
But when "A" application invokes a "B" application by "Process.Start()" method, a "hostfxr.dll failed" error occurred.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# projects using both X86 and Any CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598558/c-sharp-projects-using-both-x86-and-any-cpu)

Comment: "hostfxr.dll failed" is too vague to diagnose the issue.  Guessing: don't deploy these projects to the same directory.  They need distinct flavors of the unmanaged hostfxr.dll, the x86 project can't run with the x64 flavor of hostfxr.  Putting the console project in a subdirectory makes it easy to find back.